# Change textblock from class#.cs windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want change the text of a `TextBlock` (or property of any object) by a class file, but when I call that class I just know name of the object?

example:

```cs
<TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="25" Margin="25,220,0,0" Name="txbuser">Username :</TextBlock>
```

and I have file class.cs

How can I change the text property when I just know the name of the `TextBlock` is "txbuser"?
thanks all

Answer (score 2):

In your class file, you just need to reference the `TextBlock` instance by its name and set the `.Text` property.

```cs
txbuser.Text = "omm nom nom nom";
```

Comment: sorry i mean: I want create a class from class.cs. Then i call that from MainPage.xaml to change textblock from MainPage.xaml. So i can't find txbuser when i write code from class.cs?

Comment: If you must, expose it as a property. However, I'd recommend abstracting out a model and having the window and the class talk to the model independently.